# Unlocking range of cells in excel selected by cellname Office 2007

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have 3 cells which are merged with each other and are referenced to with a given cellname (for example "foo").

I now want to unlock these cells with the `locked` attribute.

The lock in the following code will **not** work, but the value will be successfully assigned to the cell:

```
Workbooks(loadedSheetName).Worksheets("foo").Range("bar").Locked = False
Workbooks(loadedSheetName).Worksheets("foo").Range("bar") = "foo value"
```

What will work is referencing the cells by "coordinates" but is not really an option for me:

```
Workbooks(loadedSheetName).Worksheets("foo").Range("B3:E3").Locked = False
```

Is there any possibility to select some merged cells by name and set the `locked` attribute to false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works OK in my Excel 2007

```
Sub aa()
    Dim ce As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ''# screen flicker off
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""
    For Each ce In Range("rng")
        ce.MergeArea.Locked = "False"
    Next ce
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=""
End Sub
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go through every cell in a `Range`.

Simply...

```
 Range("myRangeName").Select
 Selection.Locked = False
```